# Windows XP Indexing Service: escape #, ! or @?

Tags: windows, escaping

Open the search side bar in Windows explorer (Ctrl + F). In the field labeled, "A word or phrase in the file:" enter a query starting with #, ! or @ that you expect to return some results.

I get the following error:
The Indexing Service query cannot be completed successfully because the volumes you have specified are not indexed

Is there a way to escape these characters so the search will go through? I know about Agent Ransack and command line solutions, etc. but I'm wondering if there's an easy way to make Windows work as it's supposed to.

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure you've got the Indexing Service turned on? I only get the "query cannot be completed successfully because the volumes you have specified are not indexed" error when the service is turned off.

Have a look in **Control Panel** -> **Administrative Tools** -> **Services**, right-click **"Indexing Service"** and select **Start**.

Alternatively, from the search pane itself, click **"Change preferences"**, then **"With Indexing Service"**, then **"Yes, enable Indexing Service"**.

Comment: Correct, it is off. I use Windows Search for indexing but I'd like my unindexed searches to work too.

Answer (score 1):

Try the following types of escape sequences:

- ~=#
- ~=!
- ~=@

This ***~=*** escape sequence appears to work for Windows 7 but I'm not sure about Windows XP.

I found my solution via a similar problem that I [posted on SuperUser.com](https://superuser.com/questions/168638/trouble-trying-to-use-windows-search-to-search-for-file-with-a-question-mark-in-t/217491#217491).

Answer (score 0):

This is most likely becuase the Indexing Service is turned off. To turn it on from the Explorer search bar, you can do:

1. Go back to the **What do you want to search for?** panel
2. Click **Change Preferences** at the bottom of the panel
3. Click **With Indexing Service (for faster local searches)**
4. Click **Yes, enable the Indexing Service**, then click OK

You may have to wait a little while for the index to build (if you try your search again, it may fail as indexing is not complete). But eventually, it should work as expected.